# Mostrar un alert antes de saltar a otra pagina o cerrar el navegador

Tags: javascript

Tengo una pagina principal en la que deseo que se me muestre un 'alert' de aviso en JavaScript o se ejecute una función antes de salir de la pagina al pulsar un enlace en esta o al cerrar el navegador.

He usado los eventos 'unload' y 'beforeunload' pero no funciona.
Al inicio del JavaScript pongo el siguiente código, para que cuando salga de la pagina me llame a la función terminar que contendrá un alert de aviso.

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('unload', terminar, false);
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', terminar, false);
}
```

Con el navegador Edge si uso el evento beforeunload con addEventListener me sale un aviso al cerrar una pestaña o el navegador automáticamente sin saltar a la función terminar. Con los demás navegadores simplemente no funciona nada.

Answer (score 1):

el evento onunload (unload) se aplica al body, no al document ni al window

```
<body onunload="myFunction()">

document.body.addEventListener('unload', terminar, false);
```

Otros puntos importantes:

1. onunload pasará solamente si onload se disparó antes (es decir que la página cargó correctamente)
2. onunload es un evento estandar a partir de HTMl5
   es decir en chrome necesitas un `<!DOCTYPE html>` al principio para que funcione correctamente, sino tendrás un comportamiento aleatorio (no se en los demás navegadores)

Por otra parte, poner un alert cuando sales de la página (sea por click o por cerrar la página, cambiar de URLs, etc) es una practica muy fea y no recomendada por UX/UI y usabilidad. Y menos si es una página de internet estandar (un sistema back end eventualmente puede tener razones)

Por ejemplo sería válido si hiciste cambios en una forma de captura no guardados, pero definitivamente no válido si quieres "retener" el usuario en tu página de publicidad como tristemente hay muchas así.

Comment: No funciona, cuando hago click a un enlace de la pagina va al enlace sin mostrar antes el alert.

Comment: De hecho si aplica al window, no todo lo que ves en w3schools es cierto. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onunload

Comment: Tienes los dedos llenos de razón.

Comment: Disculpad necesito también que funcione si cierro el navegador.

Comment: Uso onload disparado antes y no funciona.

Comment: El tema es que necesito ejecutar un código antes de salir de la pagina o cerrar el navegador. El Alert seria para probar que la función es llamada.

Comment: Con el navegador Edge si uso el evento beforeunload con addEventListene me sale un aviso al cerrar una pestaña o el navegador automáticamente sin saltar a la función terminar. Con los demás navegadores simplemente no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un `confirm`, si le da aceptar que lo mande a la página que quieras, si le da en cancelar, se mantiene en la página actual. Espero sea más o menos lo que buscas.

```js
function otraPagina(){
var confirmar = confirm('Estas seguro que deseas salir?');
if (confirmar){
  
  window.location.href = 'otrapagina.html'

}else{
}
}
```

```html
<button onclick="otraPagina()">Ir</button>
```

Comment: No me sirve ya que si la pagina tiene 20 o 30 enlaces tengo que hacerlo por cada uno de ellos. Además Me tiene que servir también para cuando cierro navegador o pestaña.

Comment: Esta respuesta no contesta a la pregunta solicitada, ya que no funciona para cuando se cierra la página o el navegador

Comment: Tampoco tu respuesta ayuda a lo que solicitó el OP, y ya no contestaste a lo que solicitó después, pero gracias por estar al pendiente de mis respuestas! :D

Answer (score 0):

Amigo lo que puedes hacer es agregar una función a tu botón.
Ejemplo:

```
<a href="https://www.google.cl/" target="_blank" onclick="linkExterno();">Link a Google</a>
```

Y tu función sería la siguiente:

```
function linkExterno(){
        alert('¿Estas seguro que deseas abandonar está página?');
    }
```

Esta función la puedes agregar a todos los botones que quiera y también agregar las condiciones que necesites.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Podria servir pero necesito que salga cuando voy a otra pagina o cierro el navegador.